# Check if post has been viewed / visited (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm just wondering if there is a way to check if a post has been visited or not, basically I have a custom post type "Videos" and would like for when a user has viewed the post / video, when going back to the listing page, there would be a tick to show it's been viewed..

Is this possible? maybe using cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add meta for post when it viewed.
IN your template file just add

```
add_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'viewed', '1');
```

Or if your template not only for video post type
add if statement

```
if(is_singular('videos')){
add_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'viewed', '1');
}
```

And check if viewed wherever you have that post id

```
if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'viewed', true) == '1'){
   // this is viewed post
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To to it you can make a shortcode to add the post meta fist time the page or post is seen.

[set_seen_post] - the shortcode to add in your page anywhere, does not return anything

```
function pref_set_seen_post_func(){
    $post_id   = get_the_ID();

    // using a boolean with acf - you can do the same with wordpress functions
    if ( get_field('visto', $id_post_oferta) == false ) {
        update_field('visto', true, $post_id);
    }
}

add_shortcode( 'set_seen_post', 'pref_set_seen_post_func' );
```